# If cell is not blank show "PAID" if not display value of another cell

Tags: excel

I want to reference a cell, if that cell has data, I want it to display "PAID" in another cell ...

That is the easy part: `=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(CELL1)),"PAID",(""))`

My problem is that if there is NO data in that cell, I want it to display the value of another cell

So instead of `,("")) ...` I want to use `,("=CELL2"))`

When the cell has data it displays "PAID" as it should

If the cell has NO data it doesn't display the data of the other cell, it displays "=CELL2"

As above ...

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(CELL1)),"PAID",("(=CELL2)"))

A1 is a date
B1 is a dollar amount
C1 is either "PAID" or "=B2"
```

I want C1 to always display the value of B2 UNLESS A1 has data in that cell

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the purpose by removing the quotation marks "" and the = sign. Just do it like this:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(CELL1)),"PAID", CELL2)
```

For example, check if A2 cell is blank, if A2 is not blank, show PAID, if A2 cell is blank, show the value in B2:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),"PAID",B2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use "=CELL2", you can just use CELL2.

```
    =IF(NOT(ISBLANK(A2)),"PAID", B2)
```